# What is the best way to concat two JSONObject with same key in a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

The JSON request i get from the server side is a compressed format, since data is too large , it has been splitted to two json object in the `NextData` JSONarray , how can i combine these two objects before i can decompress and get the values . Iam not able to achieve this, any ideas would be appreciated. Thanku.

```
 "NextData": [
                    {
                        "Element": "KgYAAB+LCAAAAAAABACNZhHeKQVHiY8voyqMuQhFrakNHzb9/eiuGCeRrghvPrzll+2WzXX15f2OkTTQ/bIz3j308fjXhPqLD"
                    },
                    {
                        "Element": "u5Ot3i2FwO6KguNo7iqUhY/PitP7y+DA/HvbllSj8C+t04gzgTHrkJPVRD/w/i3wBGYBj6x2Ienh+s1Xr0/U+6LEfhKgYAAA=="
                    }
                ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function gets the root array and returns the concatenation of all elements inside of it.

```
public String concat(JSONArray data) {
    String response = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
        response += data.optJSONObject(i).optString("Element"));
    return response;
}
```